# Pass value to DBHelper class

Tags: javascript, java, sql-server

I am working on the web based application. I want to pass dbhelper class a text box value that user changes on form. Currently in my page dbhelper picks the old existing value of that field when page load or when I click on submit button.
I want to pass input text value when javascript function call before form submission. How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: For us to be able to help you, posting appropriate parts of your code will help. Also letting us know what you have tried will shed more light.

Comment: Try looking at your question and ask yourself if you think you could answer this with only the information posted. There is nowhere near enough information here. It is not at all clear what you are even trying to accomplish.

Comment: String db1 = request.getParameter("db1");
 String db = DBHelper.getGenericDescription("FLSAREFCHECK", flsadb1, paretId);


JAVASCRIPT
<input type="hidden" NAME="db1" id="db1" />

function flsaRefduplicate()
{
 
 var db3= document.forms[0]. Referance.value; 
 
if (flsadb3 == '' || flsadb3 == null)
 {
    alert('You must enter your userID');
 }
 else 
 {  
document.forms[0]. db1.value = db3 
} 
 
 var fdb = <%=db%>
 if(fdb > 0)
 {  
alert("test");  
 }
 
}